# Can rotary tool bits be used with a drill?

Tags: tools, drill

Can I use accessories like this [Dremel 110 Piece Super Accessory Kit](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Dremel-110-Piece-Super-Accessory-Kit-709-01/16782565)  with a regular drill or impact driver? 
Are there any advantages of rotary tools over impact drivers?

I would guess they might be more convenient to use because of the shape of the tool, but other then that is there something precluding me from using the bits with drill/driver?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Impact driver? I wouldn't. Those bits are so small you'll just shatter them.

Regular drill? Maybe. Most drills max out around 1000-1500 RPM, although some specialty drill models max out around 4000 RPM. On the other hand, a Dremel usually *starts* at 5000 RPM and can max out around 30,000 RPM. So depending on the bit, you might get adequate performance. But most bits will probably be completely unusable.

Comment: Running die grinder bits at drill speeds isn't very efficient. I've had to do it in a pinch. Proper tool for the job and all that. Save impact drivers for fasteners, you don't want shattered tool bit chunks flying around, hammering start stop motion doesn't work with them especially when they're cutter wheels or abrasive burrs.

Comment: yup. typical rotary tool bits are too small in diameter to reach proper cutting speed at drill RPMs. A typical grinding wheel for use with a drill might be 3-4" diameter, while a rotary tool grinding wheel is typically less than 3/4" diameter.

Comment: I'd also think using a cut-off wheel would be nearly impossible to control in a drill. If you don't hold it perfectly straight, the wheel will basically just shatter.